# how to hide android softkeys

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, softkeys

In my android app I hide soft keys bar using this:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

But the problem is when some message box or toast display then softkeys display again. 
I want to hide soft keys when any message box or toast displaying.

Is it possible.. how can i do this.

Comment: In which lifecycle method do you implement this ? onCreate() i assume

Comment: yes. onCreate()

Comment: You could wrap this up in a method and call the method every time you want to hide soft keys.

Comment: The way I code isn't match with display and hide. Is there any way to do this..

Answer (score 1):

Messages like dialogs, intent chooser, soft keyboard and toasts use a different Window than your main application window.
These extra Windows can change your SystemUiVisibility and Window flags as they appear and disappear.

What I found to work in most cases is to setup your flags in `onWindowFocusChanged` in the Activity class:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus) {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}
```

You then no longer need this code in onCreate, as window focus is also gained at activity creation.

Comment: your solution is perfect. but the problem is  I used this on video recording then displaying and hiding soft keys effect to the recorded video.

Comment: Working with these flags is always be a bit tricky. If it doesn't work as expected its usually because of window changes (the MediaController for videoview is also in a separate window). I'm not sure about your current troubles, but I would make a `setFullscreen(boolean)` method that sets the correct flags, then try calling that in all thinkable, possibly correct, places.